# How to fetch next row in Access Database

Tags: ms-access

Say there is a survey column where Questions and followed by Answers are in same column. I want to fetch the next row(Answer) for a particular Question ?

Comment: Be aware that by default, tables are just "buckets" that hold data, and there is no sense of order in a table until you supply a sort order. I would suggest that you re-visit your database design - you may need a table of questions, and then a separate table that contains the question id (a foreign key) and responses.

Comment: By Answer, you mean the correct response, not a user's actual response? Why are question and answers in same column?